# Echo shortcode in another shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

How to display shortcode in another shortCode.

```
function html_block_short_code() {
  $content_id = get_post_field('post_content', 180);
  ob_start();
  echo do_shortcode("$content_id");
  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('html_block','html_block_short_code');
```

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the wordpress website under the shortcode documentation you'll find the answer for your doubt.

```
function caption_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
   return '<span class="caption">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</span>';
}
```

Please refer to https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

On your code you could simply do something like:

```
function html_block_short_code($atts, $content = null) {
    return do_shortcode($content);
}

add_shortcode('html_block','html_block_short_code');
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The problem isn't on this function, can you please share how is your html with the codes on your post?

Comment: In content_id is shortCode by Visual Composer.  For example:


[vc_row full_width="stretch_row" css=".vc_custom_1526141292707{margin-bottom: 0px !important;background-image: url() !important;background-position: center !important;background-repeat: no-repeat !important;background-size: cover !important;}"]

I start my shortCode on post:  [html_block]

Comment: If you have [html_block] some content with short coded [/html_block] the code i adjusted now should work, the code you want to analyze is the one inside your shortcode . Or am i seeing it wrong?

Comment: function html_block_short_code($atts){

 $a = shortcode_atts( array(
  'id' => '',
 ), $atts );
 $id = $a["id"];

 $content_id = get_post_field('post_content', "$id");
 return do_shortcode("$content_id");
}
add_shortcode('html_block','html_block_short_code');

On the post page I wanna write a tag [html_block id="180"]. Thats all.